# How do I get my browser to show columns in foundation like in this tutorial?

Tags: zurb-foundation

In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UOQRXFe4Oro#t=130) the author clicks a button to show the columns in a foundation layout. How does he do that? What does he click? Does he use a plugin or something? How can I do that as well?

Answer (score 1):

its foundation overlay plugin for chrome

[Foundation Overlay](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/foundation-overlay/odknmbgidnpnihgllkebklpekefphpbn)